# If $\Delta f(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$ and $\Delta_n f(x) = \Delta \left( \Delta_{n-1} f(x) \right)$. Prove $\Delta_{n+1} P(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in R$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I am asked the following question:

**Question:** Given that $\Delta f(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$ and $\Delta_n f(x) = \Delta \left( \Delta_{n-1} f(x) \right)$, prove that for any nth degree polynomial $P(x)$ $$\Delta_{n+1} P(x) = 0 \quad  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I came up with the following solution, although I am not sure it is correct.

**My solution**
It looks like an induction proof would do the trick. Let me start with the base case (although not necessary, I actually tested for two different values of $n$)

For $n=0$: $P(x)=k$

$$\Delta_{n+1} P(x) = \Delta P(x) = P(x+1)-P(x) = k - k = 0$$ (it holds)

For $n=1$: $P(x)=ax+b$

$$\Delta_{n+1} P(x) = \Delta \left( \Delta P(x) \right) = \Delta \left( P(x+1)-P(x) \right) =$$
$$=  \Delta \left( a(x+1)+b-ax-b \right) = \Delta \left(a\right) = a-a = 0$$ (it holds)

Inductive hypothesis: Assume $\Delta_{k+1} P(x) = 0$ given $\deg P(x) \leq k$.

Inductive step:

$$\Delta_{(k+1)+1} P(x) = \Delta_{k+2} P(x) = \Delta \left( \underbrace{\Delta_{k+1} P(x)}_\text{$\deg = 0$} \right) = \Delta \left(k \right) = k - k = 0$$

Is the solution above correct?

Comment: It's incorrect. $\Delta_{k+1}P(x)$ is not necessarily $0$. What you want to do is consider $\Delta_{k+1}(\Delta P(x))$, and see that $\Delta P(x)$ is of degree one less than $P(x)$ so it satisfies the inductive hypothesis. (the inductive hypothesis being, $\Delta_{k+1} P(x) = 0$ when $\deg P(x) \leq k$)

Comment: Notice that $P(x)$ is $k + 1$ degree, not $k$.

Comment: @Jakobian so $\Delta_{k+1} P(x)$ will always be of zero degree, correct? Assuming that the degree of $P(x)$ is $\leq k$.

Comment: @bru1987 It helps to write things out clearly. EG Use $P_i$ to denote a polynomial of degree $i$. $\quad$ (Note that generally the induction hypothesis is applied at $k$, not $k+1$. That confusion can make it hard for you to express yourself clearly to others) Your induction step requires us to show that $\Delta_{k+2} P_{k+2}(x) = 0 $. You do not have any information on $\Delta_{k+1} P_{k+2} (x) $ as yet. You know know that $ \Delta_{k+1} P_{k+1} (x) = 0 $.  $\quad$ Also, avoid having your notation do double duty. Is $k$ the index you are inducting on, or the degree 0 polynomial?